# postgres, contains-operator for multidimensional arrays performs flatten before comparing?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, contains

The following query:

```
SELECT ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] @> ARRAY[2, 3, 5];
```

gets responded with true and not false as expected, since the `array[2, 3, 5]` doesn't exist in the source array. Any ideas how can it happen? Maybe flatten is applied to multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It is even scarier:

SELECT unnest(ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]);

delivers

 unnest 
--------
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9

So flattening seems to be applied :-/

Expected:
--------
      {1,2,3}
      {4,5,6}
      {7,8,9}

Comment: looks like it does preform flattening - SELECT ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] @> ARRAY[[2], [3], [5]] returns true as well

Comment: yepp, the question is WHY? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not answer why, but I've tried to find a way to do what you need, best I've got so far is:

```
with cte_arr as (
   select ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11, 12], [2,5,3]] as arr
), cte_s as (
   select generate_subscripts(arr,1) as subscript, arr
   from cte_arr
)
select arr[subscript:subscript] @> ARRAY[2, 3, 5], arr[subscript:subscript]
from cte_s
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1457)

some useful links about arrays in PostgreSQL:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)
- [Convert multi-dimensional array to records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111008/convert-multi-dimensional-array-to-records)
- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level) - still unanswered

Comment: My question indeed  should read "what is the workaround for it" and your code does exactly what I need. Thank you :)

Comment: Got some news about "why" on #postgres channel:

http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c;h=438c3d0e9e6733e89e4156259421ea9374bf8905;hb=HEAD#l3645