# Check if a group contains all the ids in any of the arrays supplied

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I pass a 2d array to a procedure. This array contains multiple arrays of ids. I want to

- group a table by group_id
- for each group, for each array in the 2d array

  - IF this group has all the ids within this iteration array, then return it

I read here about issues with 2d arrays:

[postgres, contains-operator for multidimensional arrays performs flatten before comparing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359122/postgres-contains-operator-for-multidimensional-arrays-performs-flatten-before)

I think I'm nearly there, but I am unsure how to get around the problem. I understand why the following code produces the error "Subquery can only return one column", but I cant work out how to fix it

```
DEALLOCATE my_proc;
PREPARE my_proc (bigint[][]) AS
WITH cte_arr AS (select $1 AS arr), 
     cte_s AS (select generate_subscripts(arr,1) AS subscript, 
     arr from cte_arr),
     grouped AS (SELECT ufs.user_id, array_agg(entity_id) 
    FROM table_A AS ufs
    GROUP BY ufs.user_id)
SELECT * 
FROM grouped
WHERE (select arr[subscript:subscript] @> array_agg AS sub,
    arr[subscript:subscript]
    from cte_s);
EXECUTE my_proc(array[array[1, 2], array[1,3]]);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a row for each group and each array in the parameter with a `cross join`:

```
PREPARE stmt (bigint[][]) AS
    with    grouped as
            (
            select  user_id
            ,       array_agg(entity_id) as user_groups
            from    table_A
            group by
                    user_id
            )
    select  user_id
    ,       user_groups
    ,       $1[subscript:subscript] as matches
    from    grouped
    cross join
            generate_subscripts($1, 1) as gen(subscript)
    where   user_groups @> $1[subscript:subscript]
;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f90e8/5/1)

Comment: Is there a way to remove nulls from the bigint[][]? either at the where part or ideally before

Comment: If you can use a chosen number like -1 instead of `null`, you could use `user_groups || -1 @> $1[subscript:subscript]` to ignore the -1 during matching.